# Excel: How do I compute a compound product & sum of two columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have two columns of numbers.
I need to write a formula to multiply the two columns together, and then add all of the products together.

[image]

In this case: `(16*1) + (6*0) + (4*0) + (4*0) + (4*0) + (2*0) = 16`

Normally I would just make a third column to hold the products, and then sum those.
But this table is huge, and I would have to add way too many columns for that approach to be practical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that directly with SUMPRODUCT, which does exactly the calculation in the question:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A6,B1:B6)
```

SUMPRODUCT can also be used with two-dimensional arrays, and more than two columns to be multiplied and then added.  See [Microsoft Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-16753E75-9F68-4874-94AC-4D2145A2FD2E)

Answer (score 2):

use an array function.

```
=SUM(A:A*B:B)
```

and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to finish your formula.  It will end up looking like this:

```
={SUM(A:A*B:B)}
```

from:

```
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d
```